Create a trigger in SQL which ignore rows insertion acocrding to criteria
I would like to create an SQL trigger which insert new rows in a table with conditions.
Here is an example of my sql table content :

The goal of this trigger is to check that any new inserted row cannot be inserted if there is alread a row in the table for which (col2, col3, col5) values equal the new inserted row (col2, col3, col5) values.
So in my example the trigger

should not insert in the table the new row if the row's col2=B and col4=E and col5=G

should insert the new row otherwise


I thought about something like this
`CREATE TRIGGER trig_a
ON table01
Instead OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table01
SELECT *
FROM   inserted
WHERE...
END `

why not no use unique index ?

Also please tag the actual product you are using, and don't post images of code or data.
